# How to use Eclipse generated .classpath file to specify the external libraries?

Tags: java, eclipse, batch-file

I need to start a Java application using a `.bat` file . Here is what I have so far, and it works fine

```
java  -cp ".;C:\someLibrary.jar;C:\someLibrary.jar;..." Main
```

The problem is there are too many external libraries, and Eclipse already generates a `.classpath` file referring to all those libraries. Is there any way I could use that `Eclipse generated .classpath` file in my batch, so that I don't have to list all the libraries in the `java` command above ?

Can I use something like this

```
java  -cp ".;C:\ ..\pathToEclipseFolder.classpath" Main
```

---

The reason I am asking this is because I will eventually end up updating some of those external libraries. And I want to still be able to use the original `.bat` file

Comment: Populate the manifest file....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Java application needs the libraries, then you must specify them in the classpath of your .bat file.

A couple of considerations:

1) Maybe you have more libraries listed in your Eclipse classpath than you actually need

2) Java6 and higher allows you to specify a *directory*, instead of requiring you to specify each individual library in that directory:

`java -classpath ".;c:\mylib\*" MyApp`